# React - Setting state to target with onClick method

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to recreate a tabs component in React that someone gave me and I am getting stuck while getting the onClick method to identify the target.

These are the snippets of my code that I believe are relevant to the problem.

**If I hardcode setState within the method, it sets it appropriately, so the onClick method is running, I am just unsure of how to set the tab I am clicking to be the thing I set the state to.**

On my App page:

```
changeSelected = (event) => {
// event.preventDefault();
this.setState({
  selected: event.target.value
})
console.log(event.target.value)
};

<Tabs tabs={this.state.tabs} selectedTab={this.state.selected} 
selectTabHandler={() => this.changeSelected}/>
```

On my Tabs page:

```
{props.tabs.map(tab => {
      return <Tab selectTabHandler={() => props.selectTabHandler()} selectedTab={props.selectedTab} tab={tab} />
    })}
```

On my Tab page:

```
 return (
<div
  className={'tab active-tab'}
  onClick={props.selectTabHandler(props.tab)}
>
  {props.tab}
</div>
```

When I console.log(props.tab) or console.log(event.target.value) I am receiving "undefined"

Comment: did you try adding "()" to your  () => this.changeSelected() ?  and your onClick should be like "onClick={() => props.selectTabHandler(props.tab)}
otherwise could you create a https://codesandbox.io/ with your full code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I did try the () at the end, I also changed the onClick to include () => and am still getting undefined. I haven't used codesandbox before but I will set one up and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues causing this to happen. The first issue is that you wouldn't use `event.target.value` in the `Content` component because you aren't reacting to DOM click event directly from an `onClick` handler as you are in `Tab`, instead you are handling an event from child component. Also keep in mind that `event.target.value` would only be applicable to input or similar HTML elements that have a `value` property. An element such as `<div>` or a `<span>` would not have a `value` property.

The next issues are that you aren't passing the `tab` value from `Tabs` to `Content` and then from within `Content` to it's `changeSelected()` handler for `selectTabHandler` events.

In addition the `onClick` syntax in `Tab`, `onClick={props.selectTabHandler(props.tab)}` is not valid, you will not be able to execute the handler coming from props and pass the `props.tab` value. You could instead try something like `onClick={() => props.selectTabHandler(props.tab)}`.

`Content` - need to pass `tab` value coming from child to `changeSelected()`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="content-container">
      <Tabs
        tabs={this.state.tabs}
        selectedTab={this.state.selected}
        selectTabHandler={tab => this.changeSelected(tab)}
      />
      <Cards cards={this.filterCards()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Tabs` - need to pass `tab` coming from child to `selectTabHandler()`:

```
const Tabs = props => {
  return (
    <div className="tabs">
      <div className="topics">
        <span className="title">TRENDING TOPICS:</span>
        {props.tabs.map(tab => {
          return (
            <Tab
              selectTabHandler={tab => props.selectTabHandler(tab)}
              selectedTab={props.selectedTab}
              tab={tab}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabs;
```

Also don't forget the unique `key` property when rendering an array/list of items:

```
<Tab
  key={tab}
  selectTabHandler={tab => props.selectTabHandler(tab)}
  selectedTab={props.selectedTab}
  tab={tab}
/>
```

Here is a forked [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/92pywwpy7p) demonstrating the functionality.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer. I'm sorry to say that I'm a bit confused. I see yours working but am unsure why you declared a new function in the tabs component rather than reusing what you had.

Apologies, I'm very new to this world :p

Comment: Glad to help! I structured it this way just to show it broken out to make hopefully easier to explain, it can absolutely be condensed and you can absolutely re-use the functions. That being said the syntax `onClick={props.selectTabHandler(props.tab)}` in `Tab` will not work. You could do something like `onClick={() => props.selectTabHandler(props.tab)}` though.

Comment: [Here](https://react-5kc7tg.stackblitz.io) is a more "condensed" version reusing `selectTabHandler` but with the update to `Tab`'s `onClick` syntax. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The second link doesn't show the code, unless I'm doing something wrong (very likely haha)

I've moved what I've got to a codesandbox

    https://codesandbox.io/s/9z2lyw23pp


I commented out the CSS file, but the small "all" "javascript" etc are the tabs. When I click on them, it sets state to none, I thought I changed what you said, but maybe I misunderstood? I thought that by calling the function every step of the way, it was passing it that one layer farther, as you mentioned in the beginning

Comment: I've updated the answer and created an updated/forked [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/92pywwpy7p). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. I was only trying to pass tab at the end (and I see I also put something as a string that I shouldn't have). Thanks!!!!!!